# vscode debugging failed to print std::map correctly

Tags: vscode-debugger

I'm using VScode to debug my C++ project on Ubuntu, using gdb.

I'm currently having trouble printing std::map with keys of type std::string and values of complex type(like user-defined class).

Taking this piece of code as an example:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class notused{
    notused* next = nullptr;
};


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, notused> a;
    a["1"] = notused();
    a["1::1"] = notused();

    int b = 1; // not really used
    return 0;
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on line`int b = 1;`, I try to print the map `a`.
I expect it to be like:

```
a:
  ["1"]
    next:0x0
  ["1::1"]
    next:0x0
```

Meanwhile, it is actually:

[image]

**The value "1::1" is missing!**

We use "::" as a path connector throughout our project and are unwilling to change. Is there any simple way to make the printing correct?

As a context, the gdb version is 12.1, and vscode setting is like:

```json
{
    // 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 
    // 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
    // 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) 启动",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/reproduce",
            "args":[],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "将反汇编风格设置为 Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

(update)

When I simply run gdb from command line, it's like:

```
(gdb) print a
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {
  ["1"] = {
    next = 0x0
  },
  ["1::1"] = {
    next = 0x0
  }
}
```

Also, the information in debug console when I type `-exec print a` is:

```
-exec print a
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {
  ["1"] = {
    next = 0x0
  },
  ["1::1"] = {
    next = 0x0
  }
}
```

My gdb version is : GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1

My g++ version is : gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

Comment: @starball Thx for your attention! I just updated info accordingly. It seems to launch from command line is right. (That's why I tagged this problem with vscode-debugger rather than gdb)

Comment: I'd suggest that you also [raise an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=2_debugger.yml), providing details there on how exactly to reproduce the problem. If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket, or ping me in the issue ticket with "@starball5".